# Raspberry Pi camera - multi tasking possible?

Tags: sensor, motion, picamera

I have set up 2 individual tasks using the NOIR Pi camera and a motion sensor which work successfully in their own right.

1. Using motion to stream a live video to an external ip address
2. a python script to record a video and send to my gmail acc when motion is detected. I use MOtionSnesor and piCamera for this

However task2 does not work in parallel with task1 because it is "out of resources".
Task 2 only works if I stop motion software via "sudo service motion stop".

Is there a way to have both task running in parallel?
Thanks[image]

Answer (score 1):

You would probably have to create a task 3.

It would take handle data from the camera, and then pass copies of the data to task 1 and task 2 separately.